# Dynamic Where clause in SQL - Need to solve a specific scenario

Tags: sql, oracle

I got some complexity while implementing dynamic where clause using CASE. Is there any other way to address the below problem? I will be appreciate if someone can give any solution for it.

Problem: There are two SQL queries which need to be combined to one. I tried different ways to achieve it, but failed. 
Below I have provided the 'Combined Query' which will work if the condition is generic (if only 'LIKE' operation used in both the queries), but here it is different. 'Query-1' contains 'LIKE' where as 'Query-2' is having 'NOT LIKE' operator.

### Query-1:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME X
WHERE X.COL1 = 10
AND X.LOG_DATE >= TO_DATE('07/01/2016', 'MM/DD/YYYY')
AND X.COL2 LIKE '%DATA-1%'
```

### Query-2:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME X
WHERE X.COL1 = 10
AND X.LOG_DATE < TO_DATE('07/01/2016', 'MM/DD/YYYY')
AND X.COL2 NOT LIKE '%DATA-2%'
```

### Combined Query:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME X
WHERE X.COL1 = 10 
AND X.COL2 LIKE
CASE
  WHEN (X.LOG_DATE >= TO_DATE('07/01/2016', 'MM/DD/YYYY'))
    THEN 
      '%DATA-1%'
  ELSE 
    '%DATA-2%'
END
```

Comment: Why not use UNION?

Comment: UNION removes duplicates.

Comment: Whatever approach you take, having `LIKE '%<anything>%` is going to yield a full table scan *(slow)*.

Comment: @jarlh - That's disingenuous, I'm sure that you're fully aware using `UNION ALL` *(with the `ALL`)* would be a perfectly reasonable suggestion.

Comment: @jarlh What about UNION ALL?

Comment: Depends on what OP wants. I'd go with @Gnor's query anyway.

Comment: @jarlh - Owing to the SCAN caused by the `LIKE '%<stuf>%'`, I agree.  If it was `LIKE '<stuff>%'` then I'd disagree.

Comment: Thanks Rajesh so many people have comments on this question.

Answer (score 5):

You could use an OR statement in the where clause like this:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME X
WHERE (X.COL1 = 10
AND X.LOG_DATE >= TO_DATE('07/01/2016', 'MM/DD/YYYY')
AND X.COL2 LIKE '%DATA-1%')
OR
(X.COL1 = 10
AND X.LOG_DATE < TO_DATE('07/01/2016', 'MM/DD/YYYY')
AND X.COL2 NOT LIKE '%DATA-2%')
```

Comment: I'd move out the common condition, `X.COL1 = 10`, to make it easier for the optimizer.

Answer (score 1):

Solution using case (but probably not the prettiest solution for the problem):

```
select *
  from table_name x
 where x.col1 = 10
   and (case
          when (x.log_date >= to_date('07/01/2016', 'MM/DD/YYYY'))
               and x.col2 like '%DATA-1%' then
           1 
          when (x.log_date < to_date('07/01/2016', 'MM/DD/YYYY'))
               and x.col2 not like '%DATA-2%' then
           1
          else
           0
       end) = 1
```

Comment: `CASE <whatever> END = 1` would be a more robust *(and ANSI-SQL compatible)* syntax.  *(With the `= 1`, rather than the `CASE` expressions implicitly returning a Boolean.)*

Comment: Thanks, fixed it.

Answer (score -1):

you can use UNION  or UNION ALL  with the two queries

Comment: This is only half an answer.  Please include the OP's query, or move this to a comment.

Comment: @ MatBailie  use  UNION or UNION ALL  just get only half an answer, are you sure?

Comment: This has been mentioned in several comments. Answers are supposed to add another perspective. Please read [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: i answer this before the up several comments。is not  ok？@ Reaz Murshed

Comment: This is only half an answer because it doesn't have enough information in it.  This does not mean it would only give half the results, it means that your answer is too short, incomplete, insufficient.  Not because you answered before people made comments, but because your answer doesn't show ***how*** to implement your advice.  Take the advice given to you, and please read the links on how to write a good answer.

Comment: @MatBailie  i agree with your “write a good answer” ,but i don't agree that had posted a absolute wrong  answer

Comment: I said it's only half an answer.  You should have written this as a comment *(not an answer, because it is missing far too much pertinent information)*, or provided a more complete answer.